# Does Shatpath Bramhana mention Rama?

Tags: rama, shatapatha-brahmana

I was trying to trace the earliest reference of Rama and I came to Dasrath Jataka, Mahabharata. But someone mentioned its also there in Shatpath Bramhana. Is it ?